# Selecting objects from two lists of objects

Tags: c#, linq

I have a method that takes two lists as arguments and returns a list with the objects shared by the two arguments by comparing their name. It looks like this:

```
static List<Department> InCommon(List<Department> list_a, List<Department> list_b)
{
    List<Department> a_list = new List<Department>();
    var names = list_b.Select(item => item.Name);
    a_list = list_a.Where(item => names.Contains(item.Name)).ToList();
    return a_list;
}
```

I need a second method that does something similar. It should be able to return the objects in `list_a` after having removed the objects in `list_b` from it. `list_a` minus `list_b`, so to speak. I suspect

```
List<T>.Except
```

might be the solution, but how can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

To use `Except` you would need to implement an `IEqualityComparer<Department>` that compares two `Department` instances by their `Name` properties.

So an easier way may be this:

```
return list_a.Where(a => list_b.All(b => a.Name != b.Name)).ToList();
```

This takes all elements from `list_a` with a `Name` that does not occure in `list_b`.

---

For the `Except` version you would need an `IEqualityComparer<Department>` like this:

```
public class DepartmentByNameComparer : IEqualityComparer<Department>
{
    public bool Equals(Department x, Department y)
    {
        return x.Name == y.Name;
    }
    public int GetHashCode(Department obj)
    {
        return obj.Name.GetHashCode();
    }
}
```

Then you could call `Except` like this:

```
return list_a.Except(list_b, new DepartmentByNameComparer()).ToList();
```

Comment: Brilliant. Your first suggestion works like a charm. 
Thank you.